# RegEx match table cell

Tags: regex

RegEx question again

I'm using PCRE syntax and I'm trying to find a solution for matching cells in a simplified table (like in trac)

let say we have:

```
||cell||cell||cell||
||cell||cell||cell
||cell||||cell||
    ||other table cell||
```

OK, I need to make two tables out of above, (second line misses an ending, third has a colspan=2 at second cell)

The idea is simple I must catch every occurrence of ||cell
I'm interested to catch even occurrences of | and all the text to next occurrence of double | or new line, also I need to avoid ! before pipes, and know the distance from the beginning of line.

I spend whole day trying to do this... maybe I'm to stupid... or maybe .NET has some verid implementation of RegEx.

Comment: Do you believe regular expressions are the best solution for that? What about tokenizing the string and then parsing it?

Comment: You need to clarify your question and add the best of your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after hours of fights and throwing things I finally got it! Behold:

```
/(?<tr>\n\s*|\A\s*)?(?<td>(!?\|\|)+)(?<th>=)?(?<content>(?<left>[ ]*).*?(?<right>[ ]*))(?<fold>\|\|\s?\\)?(?=(!?\|\|)|(?<eol>\n|\Z))/gm
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Test on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/qQ9nU9)

Answer (score 1):

This grabs the content of every cell, is that what you're talking about?

```
(?<=\|\|)[^|\r\n]*
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/hJ3hZ7)

**Explanation**

```
  (?<=                     # look behind to see if there is:
    \|                     #   '|'
    \|                     #   '|'
  )                        # end of look-behind
  [^|\r\n]*                # any character except: '|', '\r' (carriage
                           # return), '\n' (newline) (0 or more times
                           # (matching the most amount possible))
```

Comment: Almost nailed. I personally came up with something like this: (?<td>(^\s+)?!?\|{2})+(?<content>.*)(?<tdortr>(?!\|\||\n)) but it doesn't work as expected [link](http://regex101.com/r/hJ3hZ7). From the above I need to catch couple of '||cell', one '  ||other table cell', one '||||cell', one '||cell' (with knowledge about line ending) and three '||' (with knowledge about line ending). I considered parsing string manually, but all other parts of tokenizer use regex so I think it would fit in nicely.